# convergence $f\ast \rho_{\epsilon}\to f$ when $\epsilon \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let $(\rho_{\epsilon})_{\epsilon\ge 0}$ be mollifiers, i.e. $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\rho_{\epsilon}\ge 0, \int \rho_{\epsilon} = 1$ and $supp(\rho_{\epsilon})\subset B(0,\epsilon)$. I want to study the convergence $f\ast \rho_{\epsilon}\to f$ when $\epsilon \to 0$. So I can write $(f\ast \rho_{\epsilon}-f)(x)=\int_{B(0,\epsilon)}(f(x-y)-f(y))\rho_{\epsilon}(y)dy$. Now I see that if f would be uniformly continuous we would have $\lvert f(x-y)-f(y) \rvert < s$ for $y\in B(0,\epsilon)$ and so we have uniform convergence.
Now if I assume f only continuous then for each $x$ fixed and each $s$ there is $\epsilon_x$ such that $\lvert f(x-y)-f(y)\rvert<s$ for $y\in B(0,\epsilon_x)$. So we would have pointwise convergence. But what if $f$ is not continuous? I thought that mollifiers kind of smooth out the function and we would still have convergence.

Comment: Are you looking at $L^1$ convergence?

Comment: I was thinking about what I could say for pointwise convergence, $L^1$ convergence or any type of convergence.

Comment: There is a classical result like this: If $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ is open and $f\in \mathcal C(U)$, then $f*\rho_{\varepsilon}\to f$ uniformly on every *compact* subset of $U$. I don't think we have uniform convergence on all of $U$ in general.

Comment: Yes because a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous right? And if f not even continuous we cannot say anything right?

Comment: The answer to the first question is "yes" and the answer to the second question is also "yes." (For instance, if $f$ is the Heaviside function, it is $L^1_{\text{loc}}$, so $\rho_\varepsilon * f$ is $\mathcal C^\infty$ so there can be no uniform convergence to $f$.)

Comment: Interesting. Can you hint or redirect to a proof that if $f\in L^1_{loc}$ then $\rho_{\epsilon}\ast f$ is $C^{\infty}$? Also we cannot say anything about uniform convergence but what about pointwise convergence?

Comment: You can prove, I think directly from the definitions, that $$(f*g)'(x)=(f'*g)(x).$$ So if $f$ is $\mathcal C^\infty$, then so is $f*g$. I don't have the time to think about (almost sure) pointwise convergence right now though, sorry